# Problem with data encoding in PDU response

Tags: sharp-snmp

I get some incorrect character in some of my pdu response variable data.
The data is OctetString type.

The value of the oid is correct in MibBrowser.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/tutorials/octet-strings.html

Comment: Thanks for this information. In fact, after somme debugging, it seems that the problem comes from the DateAndTime format in some mibs module. Do you know how I can convert from the byte array of the DateAndTime to a correct OctetString ? Thanks for you help.

Comment: Unfortunately, only with #SNMP Pro such data structures are supported, https://blog.lextudio.com/snmp-pro-dateandtime-syntax-support-e99abc51bc2f #SNMP Library does not have capabilities of MIB documents.